# SwiftUI Photo Gallery View Smooth Scrolling

Tags: swiftui, lazyvgrid

I'm building a photo gallery using SwiftUI, and am trying to ensure that a user can smoothly scroll through thousands of photo thumbnails without performance degradation or visible load times for each photo.

So far, my research has led me to use a **lazyvgrid** within a ScrollView, which seems to perform better than a **lazyvstack** or a normal **grid** when working with a large data set. However, when scrolling through the lazyvgrid, it takes a moment for each new row of thumbnails to load (since lazyvgrid is *lazy*), and this is especially noticeable when scrolling very quickly.

Ultimately, I'm wondering how other apps with photo galleries get around this issue. Is it impossible to avoid when using SwiftUI, and would I need to use something like UIKit's CollectionView with prefetching?

Here's what I'm doing currently:

```
ScrollView {
    LazyVGrid(columns: vGridLayout) {
        ForEach(photoLibraryService.items, id: \.self) { asset in
            PhotoThumbnailView(assetLocalId: asset.localIdentifier, mediaType: asset.mediaType, duration: asset.duration)
        }
    }
}
```

And here's what it looks like when I scroll through it quickly:

[image]

Comment: They don't use SwiftUI, when it comes to performance UIKit is much more efficient. SwiftUI is still in its infancy.

Comment: yup as @loremipsum ipsum said, they do not use SwiftUI. UICollectionView is way to go here

Comment: also take a look at WaterFallGrid library, it is slightly better than SwiftUI's own grid

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I know my response is pretty delayed here, but I ended up using a UICollectionView in conjunction with the rest of my SwiftUI code (after some trial and error)